# Does CGI stand for anything in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking at some examples, I came across lines like:

```
output.safe_concat("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"#{k}\" name=\"#{CGI.escape(k)}\" value=\"#{CGI.escape(v)}\"/>")
```

That rely on the `CGI` class.  When I Googled `CGI Rails` I found the documentation that said:

> CGI is a large class, providing several categories of methods, many of
>   which are mixed in from other modules. Some of the documentation is in
>   this class, some in the modules CGI::QueryExtension and
>   CGI::HtmlExtension. See CGI::Cookie for specific information on
>   handling cookies, and cgi/session.rb (CGI::Session) for information on
>   sessions.

Just out of curiosity, what does `CGI` stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGI stands for Common Gateway Interface.

Answer (score 0):

[Common ​​​​​​​​Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).